# A question on countably tightness space

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ weakly countably tight at $x$, if there is a countable subset $A$ of $X\setminus\{x\}$ such that $\{x\}$ is in the closure of $A$. We say that $X$ is weakly countably tight if $X$ is weakly countably tight at every $x\in X$.

> Does a weakly countably tight space have isolated?

In the theorem 13 of this paper: Sharp bases and weakly uniform bases versus point-countable bases, it shows that such space has isolated point. However, by the definition of weakly countably tight, it seems that it cannot have isolated points.

Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of weak countable tightness in that paper isn’t quite correct: it should say that $X$ is weakly countably tight if it is weakly countably tight at each **non-isolated** point of $X$.

In [this paper](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/118999) Scott Williams and Haoshuan Zhou define weak tightness at a point and weak tightness more carefully:

> Suppose $x$ is a point in a space $X$. Let $\operatorname{wt}(x,X)=\aleph_0\cdot\min\{|A|:x\in\operatorname{cl}(A)\setminus A\}$ and let $\operatorname{wt}(X)=\sup\{\operatorname{wt}(x,X):x\in X\}$.